# Log4j : put the dataPattern before extension

Tags: java, log4j

In my `DailyRollingFileAppender`, I wish to put de `datePattern` before the file extension, for example

- today's logfile : myFile.log
- yesterday's logfile : myFile.**2013-09-22**.log

How to do that ?

I'm using Log4j 1.2.16

Comment: Try `<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />` inside `<appender>`

Comment: Already tried, but the file for today have no extension in that case :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have made the modification based on this source code:
https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.java

On line 231 instead of this:

```
scheduledFilename = fileName+sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified()));
```

I use this:

```
String fileNameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
scheduledFilename = fileNameWithoutExt + sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified())) + fileExt;
```

and on line 311 instead of this:

```
String datedFilename = fileName+sdf.format(now);
```

I have made the same modification:

```
String fileNameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
String datedFilename = fileNameWithoutExt + sdf.format(now) + fileExt;
```

Works as expected.